# Generating Runtime code(structs,classes) in C#

Tags: c#, .net, code-generation, c++-cli, runtime

I need to generate structs and classes at run time in C# (might be in CLI) managed environment.
Suppose I have all data and data types associated with those data memebers of some class/struct. Now I need to generate structs/classes at runtime, and after that I need to map data inside those runtime created struct fields.

I have read data from an XML file (i.e. BSTR field1, BSTR field2, BSTR field3, BSTR field4, BSTR field5, long field6).

Now I need to create a struct at runtime which has `sizeof` the sum of all fields (which I listed above) and then I can easily access those fields one by one, so that whole completed struct is formed.

How can I solve this problem?

Regards,

Usman

Comment: How do you plan to "access those fields one by one" after you've generated the type?  Using reflection?  Since the types are dynamically generated, you would not be able to statically acess those properties.

Answer (score 3):

You need to check [CodeDom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.codedom.aspx) and [Reflection.Emit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3y322t50.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Dynamically generated typed object may help in your scenario. Vladimir Bodurov has [written about it](http://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-framework/dynamically-generating--typed-objects-in-.net/) including source code (which I would post here if it was smaller).

Answer (score 0):

`System.Reflection.Emit` has all the tools you need to make that happen.  Start with [`TypeBuilder`](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBIQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Flibrary%2Fsystem.reflection.emit.typebuilder.aspx&ei=OCZcTPWKOsP68Aa7xozqAQ&usg=AFQjCNHdtLIrV6Y5smECfxClR_0W74_GWg).